# saving multilined text from a textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to save a multilined textbox to a file but in a format like this

```
"string" + textbox1.text + "string"
"string2" + textbox1.text + "string2"
```

I have it working but only saving the

```
textbox1.text
```

part but not the string part

The result should be

taskkill /f /im + textBox1.text + /t

taskkill /f /im + textBox1.text + /t

But I don't know how to save it so it adds taskkill /f /im and /t

ok here is the code

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\value1.txt", "taskkill /f /im " + TextBox1.Text + " /t", False)
```

but when I click save the output is this

- taskkill /f /im program1
- program2
- program3
- /t

when I should be

- taskkill /f /im program1 /t
- taskkill /f /im program2 /t

Comment: you might start by showing us the actual code where you do your saving - next you might want to add an question

Comment: well its a file maker its saves a .bat file with the lines taskkill /f /im + textbox1.text + /t

Comment: that still does not show us the code where you save your strings to disk - and it's not even valid code this time ...

Comment: There I have changed the question and have added the code

Comment: so you want your prefix/suffix for **each line** - have a look at `String.Split` and `String.Join` - basically you have to split your input into lines, wrap your text around each single line (use LINQs `Select` or a loop if you want) and then `Join` them together again with `\n` ... btw: your code does exactly what you told it to do - and you really should not call your controls `textbox1` ...

Comment: OK thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process each line from the TextBox. You can use `TextBox.Lines` to get an array with one element for each line. Then you can concatenate your two strings with each line.

```
Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Lines.Select(Of String)(Function(s) "taskkill /f /im " & s & " /t").ToArray
IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\value1.txt", lines)
```